# getNetwork state does not give if i can connect to the internet

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-networking

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) 
    {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();


        if (ni == null) 
        {
            // There are no active networks.
            return false;
        }
        else if(ni.isAvailable() && cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == State.CONNECTED)
        {
            Log.i("NetworkState","Wifi Connected");
            return true;
        }
           else
          {
                    return false;
          }
}
```

This method returns `true` even if i am connected to a router which do not have an Internet Connection. What should i do to decide that if i will be able to connect to internet.

Or should i Ping to my server or google.com first to decide if i have internet?

Comment: Best to make a request to your server to check.

Answer (score 0):

try this function:

```
private final boolean isInternetOncheck() {
    ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (!(connec.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connec.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && connec.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())) {
        Log.d(TAG+"Internet not aviable");
        ErrorDialog.dispDialog(MainList.this, getString(R.string.internet_is_not_available), getString(R.string.eliteerp));
        return false;
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG+"Internet available");
        return true;
    }
}
```

with permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```